# Pandas Conditional True

Tags: python, pandas

Let say I have 2 data frames with 1,0 (True or False). Let the first one be `a` and the second one be `b`. Is there a way to avoid looping such that whenever the `a` is true and `b` is true any time within the last n observations return true? So for example, lets assume `n=2`, in the example below, since `a` on `2019-10-11` is true, we will look at `b` column and if its also true within the last `n` observation, column `a` on `2019-10-11` is valid or set to true. else it will be zero.

```
            a  b
2019-10-08  0  0
2019-10-09  0  0
2019-10-10  0  1
2019-10-11  1  0
2019-10-14  0  0
2019-10-15  0  0
2019-10-16  0  0
```

My attempt below, too slow...

```
def compute_stats(z,n,df):
    #print()
    end_idx = z.iloc[0].Index

    if (df.iloc[(end_idx-n):end_idx,1] * 1).sum() > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

x = data1.cumsum()
x.name = "Signal"

df = pd.concat([data1,data2,x],axis=1)
df['Index'] = list(range(0,len(data1)))
tmp = df.groupby("Signal").apply(lambda z: compute_stats(z,n,df))
```

In my attempt, I essentially create a separate ID column grouped by each signal. From there I did a group by. Within the function I called inside groupby, I just looked back to see if there are any True values in column `b`.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do with `ffill` with `limit`

```
df.a.eq(1)&df.b.mask(df.b==0).ffill(limit=2).eq(1)
Out[205]: 
2019-10-08    False
2019-10-09    False
2019-10-10    False
2019-10-11     True
2019-10-14    False
2019-10-15    False
2019-10-16    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Technically, shouldn't limit=2 be limit=n-1?